# Percentage layout not adding up in IE6

Tags: css

IE6 is giving me issues of course. I'm having problems with my layout using percents. The code I have looks like the following:

```
    <div style="width: 92%; margin-left: 4%; margin-right: 4%; background-color: red; height: 20px;">
        <div style="display: inline; float: left; margin-left: 1%; margin-right: 1%; width: 23%; background-color: blue; height: 20px;"></div>
        <div style="display: inline; float: left; margin-left: 1%; margin-right: 1%; width: 73%; background-color: yellow; height: 20px;"></div>
    </div>
```

So the inner two divs both have right and left margins of 1%, so a total of 4% of margins. Then the widths are 23% and 73% for a total of 96% width for the inner divs. So adding the margins and widths together, we come out to a nice 100%.

But IE6 for some reason doesn't agree, and breaks my two inner divs and places each on a new line. Does anyone know why? It works for every other browser. I took care all of the IE6 bugs I could think. The display: inline should take care of the double margin bug, and it doesn't appear to be an issue.

Here's the url if anyone wants to see it in action: http://dev1.twinmed-dev.com/test.html

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You may need to read the 960 Spec again. You're using alpha and omega together on the same element from time to time.

Comment: "Only issue I'm having is with IE6." Classic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE6 is no good at working out percentages is about the size of the problem:

http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/percentages.html

You'll notice that if you slowly resize the window in IE6 and the page reflows, every now and again your 2 divs will magically sit on the same line as you wanted.

I've always found a good reliable workaround to this issue (aside from not using percentages) is to make sure that the total is always 99%. Obviously that can compromise the layout sometimes, but using a conditional-commented IE6 only rule minimises the effect.

Answer (score 0):

IE6 is rubbish at percentages when in Standards mode.

The [positioniseverything](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/percentages.html) article is probably one of the most unreadable on the Internet, but the simple answer is that there is no simple answer.

Width 99% would solve the problem, but anyone working on a designer layout won't be able to tolerate that kind of error.

My solution is to calculate the percentages yourself, using expressions, in your IE stylesheet.

My test case is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-gb">
<head></head>
<body>
    <div style="width:50%;float:left">Left</div>
    <div style="width:50%;float:left">Right</div>
</body>
</html>
```

which jumps all over the shop when you resize the browser window.

And I can amend it for IE6 like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-gb">
<head></head>
<body>
    <div style="width:expression(this.parentNode.offsetWidth/2);float:left">Left</div>
    <div style="width:expression(this.parentNode.offsetWidth/2);float:left">Right</div>
</body>
</html>
```